# How to close activities which are appeared only once?

Tags: android

I am creating an app which consists of main, register, option activities. Main and register activities should be started only once. I got it. Problem is they are again appearing when I just going back to my mobile home page without clicking exit. Even if I do not click the exit and goes back to home, they should not appear again when I entered!! Is this possible? I am not able to get the solution for this. Any one please help me.. Thankyou

Comment: What exit action ? There isn't / shouldn't be ANY exit action.

Comment: The activities should not appear when I goes back to home in mobile with out clicking exit..

Comment: Dude... there *SHOULDN'T* be ANY exit button inside or outside your application. This isn't Windows for **** sake....

Answer (score 0):

you can override the method onStop() and put finish() there.
So, when the activity will be not longer visible, it will finish. Or you can put finish() after startActivity() call method.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by.

```
Button button15 =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button5);
    button15.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


            public void onClick(View view) {


                finish();

                }
            }
            );
```

Comment: When we goes out from the app without clicking the exit button, the activities are again appearing when I re enters.. It is not happening when I click exit button and exits from the app.